# MongoDB&NodeJS: How to display a certain field on a Jade file on a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

So I just started learning MEAN and I want to show only a certain field of a database I've made to a Node server. I'm using Express as well. Here is my code so far.

index.js

```
router.get('/generate', function(req, res) {
// get out mongoclient to work with our mongo server
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// where the mongodb server is
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/data';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to server', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established');

        var collection = db.collection('compliments');

        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else if (result.length) {
                res.json(result); // problem here
            } else {
                res.send('No documents found');
            }

            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

});

generate.jade

```
doctype html
html
head
    title("Compliment Generator")
body
    h1 !{title}
    block content
        h3.
            !{compliment}
```

This is what it looks like on localhost:3000/generate

```
[{"_id":"570b50f8265f2536d2fd6ed6","type":"compliment","content":"You are absolutely gorgeous."},{"_id":"570b50f8265f2536d2fd6ed7","type":"compliment","content":"You are wonderful."},{"_id":"570b50f8265f2536d2fd6ed8","type":"compliment","content":"I could look at you all day."}]
```

How do I make it so that it only displays the "content"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only want the content to be returned from the query.

The below link should be of use:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

You essentially want to modify the query to only retrieve the "Content" part like so:

```
collection.find({}, { content: 1, _id:0 })
```

This will specify that you don't want to include the "_id" (which is included by default) and you do want to include the "content".

Comment: Thanks! Now it's displaying like this: [{"content":"You are absolutely gorgeous."},{"content":"You are wonderful."},{"content":"I could look at you all day."}], how would I get rid of the "content" part and just show the actual compliments?

Comment: You access the elements like a key value pair so `result[0].content` would give you the value of the `content` field for the first element. You can iterate through those with a for loop or any other desired iteration pattern you need.

Comment: My previous comment won't let me edit it for some reason. Just an extra note, if it's still a JSON string you will have to parse it into a javascript object with the following syntax `JSON.parse(result);`